# Unable to putty using ssh at port 22

Tags: putty

I installed linux on one of my system and assigned valid network ip to it.
I am able to connect to net properly.

But when I try to putty this system from another system using ssh at port 22 then it gives me connection timed out error.
When I ping the system it responds fine but still unable to ssh it.

What might be the issue and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I would first check that port 22 is open configured properly.  I would additionally check that SSH is installed - my preference is OpenSSH - and that it is configured to accept incoming connections on port 22.  I would also check that there is not a firewall either setup or that a rule within the firewall is preventing connections to port 22.

Comment: This will require command access to your linux box -

run "ssh -v" without the double quotes, this should tell you what version and SSH rpm you have installed (if any).

If you do not have any installed, you can navigate over to [link]http://www.openssh.org and find the necessary instructions on how to install and configure SSH on your machine.

Comment: The issue is resolved as I disabled the remote firewall which was blocking the ssh.
It was really frustrating as all was fine and even telnet was working but not ssh.

Presently following the links http://yourlinuxguy.com/?p=468 and
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E20815_01/html/E20821/givag.html
I have disabled complete firewall.
But is there any way I can enable the firewall and ask firewall to allow ssh?
I did not see any option for the same in firewall init and setup files.

Answer (score 0):

The server in question may not be allowing logins as root. If so, you may need to log in using another username that also has admin privileges and then use the SU command to assume root privileges.